# How can I write a test for this python function?

Tags: python, function, testing, pytest, assert

How can I write pytest for this function using python.

```
def func(name):
return 'first' in name or 'second' in name
```

Comment: You have to actually call your function in the test.

Comment: Does https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#create-your-first-test help?

Answer (score 2):

Just test the truthiness of the output?

```
def test_func():
    assert func("first")
    assert func("second")
    assert not func("last")
```

Comment: I was going to note in my otherwise identical answer that you can't exhaustively test whether every string *other* than `"first"` produces a return value of `False`, and that it's up to you to decide how many other strings you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(name):
return 'first' in name or 'second' in name

def test_func():
    true_first_condition = func(name="first name")
    assert true_first_condition is True
    false_first_condition = func(name="last name")
    assert false_first_condition is False

    true_second_condition = func(name="second name")
    assert true_second_condition is True
    false_second_condition = func(name="last name")
    assert false_second_condition is False

    all_condition = func(name="first second")
    assert all_condition is True
```